# Facebook graph - Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am quite new to the Facebook API and I am getting "Invalid OAuth access token" for every API cal. I am wondering if this is because I do not have the `attribution_read` permission. Do you have some idea why I am getting this error?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/?
    ids='xxx'
    &fields=conversion_events
        .metric_scope({
            "filters":{
                "click_lookback_window":"2419200",
                "view_lookback_window":"86400",
                "visit_configuration":"include_paid_organic"
            },
            "time_period":"last_thirty_days"
        })
    {id,name,cost_per_1k_impressions,cost_per_click,cost_per_visit,net_media_cost,report_click_through_rate,report_clicks,report_impressions,report_visits,last_touch_convs,last_touch_convs_per_1k_impress,last_touch_convs_per_click,last_touch_convs_per_visit,last_touch_cpa,last_touch_revenue,last_touch_roas,total_conversions,
     metrics_breakdown
        .dimensions(["source_channel"])
        {source_channel,cost_per_1k_impressions,cost_per_click,cost_per_visit,net_media_cost,report_click_through_rate,report_clicks,report_impressions,report_visits,last_touch_convs,last_touch_convs_per_1k_impress,last_touch_convs_per_click,last_touch_convs_per_visit,last_touch_cpa,last_touch_revenue,last_touch_roas}
    }
    &access_token='xxx'
```

**result**

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "fbtrace_id": "AjUvi6I-M2NgNq5HdmKZG62"
   }
}
```

[image: permissions]

Comment: You did not actually put single quote around the value, right?

Comment: I did not use single quote around the ids and access token, no

Comment: Where exactly did you generate that token, what exactly is that what your screenshot shows there? Did you put that token through the FB token debugger, what did that say?